# BotFramework-Teams-Authentication issue `GetSignInResource` fails often

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-authentication

I am building a bot for Teams and I need to authenticate the user in order to do Microsoft Graph API calls.

As you may know, [one of the first step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-overview) in the authentication process is to generate a OAuth card. One of the endpoint fails very often, making the process fail.

I am not using `Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.OAuthPrompt`, but its low-level methods. Here are the sources:

```cs
this.ssoOptions = new OAuthPromptSettings
{
    ConnectionName = this.AzureConnectionName,
    Text = "Autoriser l'accès à vos données ?",
    Title = "Demande d'autorisation",
    Timeout = (int)MaxDelayToAuthenticate.TotalMilliseconds, //  TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5D)
    EndOnInvalidMessage = true,
};

protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turn, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    // more code here...

    if (startAuthentication)
    {
        DomainError error = null;
        var prompt = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
        try
        {
            // this will do
            // - GET https://api.botframework.com/api/botsignin/GetSignInResource
            // - send an activity
            // - later send a TokenExchangeOperationName activity through OnTurn()
            this.Logger.LogTrace($"RelaySemanticResponse: about to generate+send OAuth card with ConnectionName " + this.ssoOptions.ConnectionName);
            await OAuthPrompt.SendOAuthCardAsync(this.ssoOptions, turn, prompt, cancel);
            this.Logger.LogInformation($"RelaySemanticResponse: generate+send OAuth card with ConnectionName " + this.ssoOptions.ConnectionName + " DONE");
        }
        catch (HttpOperationException ex)
        {
            // this occurs too often!
            // Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
            this.Logger.LogError($"RelaySemanticResponse: failed to generate+send OAuth card, HTTP error: " + ex.Message);
            error = new DomainError("ExternalError", ex.ToString(), null);
        }

        if (error != null) {
            // handle error
        }
    }

    // more code here...
}
```

Sometimes, this works, and I get a trace like this:

> trce: MyBot[0]
>      MyBot.RelaySemanticResponse: about to generate+send OAuth card with ConnectionName xxx
> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
>      Sending HTTP request GET https://api.botframework.com/api/botsignin/GetSignInResource?state=%3D%3D
> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
>      Sending HTTP request POST https://smba.trafficmanager.net/emea/v3/conversations/xxx/activities/xxx
> info: MyBot[0]
> **RelaySemanticResponse: generate+send OAuth card with ConnectionName xxx DONE**
> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
>      Sending HTTP request POST https://api.botframework.com/api/usertoken/exchange?userId=xxxx&connectionName=xxx&channelId=msteams
> trce: MyBot[0]
>      MyBot.OnTurnAsync: TokenExchangeOperation! will tryRecognize
> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
>      Sending HTTP request POST https://api.botframework.com/api/usertoken/exchange?userId=xxxx&connectionName=xxx&channelId=msteams
> info: MyBot[0]
>      **MyBot.OnTurnAsync: got the token!**

But most of the times, I get this:

> trce: MyBot[0]
> MyBot.RelaySemanticResponse: about to generate+send OAuth card with ConnectionName xxx
> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[100]
> Sending HTTP request GET https://api.botframework.com/api/botsignin/GetSignInResource?state=xxxx
> info: System.Net.Http.HttpClient.Default.ClientHandler[101]
> **Received HTTP response headers after 115.2459ms - 404**
> fail: MyBot[0]
> **MyBot.RelaySemanticResponse: failed to generate+send OAuth card, HTTP error:   Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'**

When I wait a few days, it may work a few times before it starts failing for a period.

What's going on with the `https://api.botframework.com/api/botsignin/GetSignInResource` endpoint? Why does it return a HTTP 404?

---

Digging into [`OAuthPrompt.SendOAuthCardAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/868531d239ae31ddec1eaac6e181b42e189bf3fc/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/OAuthPrompt.cs#L100), I see a call to [`UserTokenAccess.GetSignInResourceAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/868531d239ae31ddec1eaac6e181b42e189bf3fc/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs/Prompts/UserTokenAccess.cs#L34). It then goes into [`userTokenClient.GetSignInResourceAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/ef116c9f28d7bc8b5d05e7251240f1c78157df90/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/Authentication/UserTokenClientImpl.cs#L60)  (of type `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Authentication.UserTokenClientImpl`). The `state` variable is a base64 JSON with some information. When I compare a success and a failure, there are no structural differences between states.

---

More information in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d):  [fail log](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-log-failing-log), [state variable leading to success](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-state-ok-json), [state variable leading to failure](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-state-fail-json),
and more source codes: [bot class](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-mycustomermyproductbot-cs), [bot parent class](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-myproductbot-cs), [dialog session singleton](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-remoteclientservice-cs), [startup.cs](https://gist.github.com/sandrock/24e0ff9c4b2e04e112a5e5ce6a8b448d#file-startup-cs).

---

The HTTP response from GetSignInResource is:

```
{"error": {"code": "ServiceError","message": "Bot does not exist"}}
```

How can that be an intermittent failure? The bot exists because the call may succeed sometimes! Something is wrong behind this endpoint!

---

I tried to add the missing domain (login.microsoftonline.com) in the app manifest [as described here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/8843#issuecomment-997665486) but to no avail.

---

Considering this is may be a framework bug, I posted a ticket https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6598 on github.

Comment: If there are too many requests being made within a specific time frame, exceeding the rate limits set by the Microsoft Bot Framework.

Implementing a retry mechanism can help handle these situations. You can catch the exception and retry the operation after a brief delay.
Ref Doc: [Optimize your bot with rate limiting in Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit)

Comment: It is also possible that the authentication process is being blocked by a firewall or other security measure. To resolve this issue, it is recommended to check the authentication settings and credentials, as well as any firewall or security settings that may be blocking the authentication process.

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, do a dozen requests per hour, as I am developing, may generate rate limiting?

Comment: @Sourav the request succeeds from time to time, I do not believe any security measure on my side would block and not block similar connections.

Comment: In the code, what is the value of `turn` and `cancel`? Also have you edited the logs (in particular `state=...`) or are these exactly the logs you're getting?

Comment: @evilmandarine for `turn` and `cancel` I edited the code to show more context. Yes, I removed some bits from the log file, for privacy reasons. Should I reveal the `state` component of the URL being called to help you debug? How can I check what's in there?

Comment: I tested with 12 employees today. It failed 11 times, for the 12th it succeeded 2 times, then I had one more success and one more failure. This `GetSignInResource` endpoint is driving me mad.

Comment: @SandRock No need to show the content, but as it is clearly the `GET GetSignInResource` call that is failing, the `state` parameter is probably relevant (does it change at every call, is it sometimes empty or equal to `==` = `%3D%3D`), hence my question. Did you look at the HTTP headers that are sent with each request (assuming you're able to trace them somehow as it seems this request is generated by the library)? Finally as @Nivedipa said, it may be worth checking if you're not above [rate limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/rate-limit).

Comment: Another possible test is test different frequencies (to perform this call 1 every minute, 5 minutes, 30min, 1h, 2h) and let it run overnight. If you're on a free/trial platform it is likely you're sharing resources with a lot of people so it can become saturated and might have nothing to do with your code.

Comment: @evilmandarine About the state variable: I added 2 samples for success and failure, they are structurally equal, only a few IDs change. To me it looks like a bug behind the endpoint; too bad I cannot see the full HTTP response. About Azure, I use a "Pay-as-you-go" resource group. About rate limits, I do less that 50 calls per day during development. The linked doc indicates a status code of 429 when rate limit occurs, and the code I get is 404. I added a log file (see question edit) that contains a few HTTP headers.

Comment: The HTTP 404 response from GetSignInResource is:

`{"error": {"code": "ServiceError","message": "Bot does not exist"}}`